# Prime static array for a number class

Tags: java, static, primes, hashset

I would like to make a Number class that has a static set of prime numbers.

I want the numbers to be stored in a static set for the class but I want to add the numbers to the set as the class is asked to find prime numbers. As in I only want to add numbers to this set when a separate method for testing a prime number is called and a prime number is found.

For some reason the static final set erases itself when another class uses this class (Number).

Here is some of my code for the Number class.

```
public class Number {

    private int number;
    static final HashSet<Integer> pSet = new HashSet<>();
    static {
        pSet.add(2);
    }

    public Number(int n) {
        number = n;
    }

    public boolean isPrime() {
        boolean out = true;
        if (number == 1) { return true; }
        if (pSet.contains(number)) { return true; }
        for (int i : pSet) {
            if (number%i == 0) {
                out = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (out) { pSet.add(number); }
        return out;
    }
}
```

How can I make this set not override itself but not be statically defined?

Comment: Could you post up the code that you're using to call this class too, please?

Comment: This looks like a straightforward memoization technique and nothing in the code *that you've shown* would account for pSet getting erased. Your isPrime() method looks wrong (1 isn't a prime for example), and just because a number isn't divisible by something in the cache doesn't mean it is prime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the original post, contained some misunderstandings.. here is a suggested fix:

```
public class Number 
{
    public static HashSet<Integer> pSet;
    static 
    {
        pSet = new HashSet<>();
        pSet.add(2);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) 
    {
        boolean out = true;
        if (n == 1) { return true; }
        if (pSet.contains(n)) { return true; }

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                out = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (out) { pSet.add(n); }
        return out;
    }
}
```

in my opinion 'isPrime' method should be static.. there is no point to create an instance of a class just to run a test over a number

the role of pSet (as declared by the submitter) is to hold a cache of previously tested prime numbers (so every number tested once)

Comment: I don't understand your response. Why would its being static cause it to get "erased"? Perhaps I don't understand what OP means by erased, but with it being a static variable, that means it won't get erased, but will continue to accumulate elements?

Comment: the word "erased" was just a description.. but i do agree that this post need editing

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. In the code that you have posted up, the Set should not be erased, because you have defined it as static. Are you saying that when you make it not static, then it gets erased when you call the class?

I'm assuming that the class works as you have posted it, but you want to make the Set non-static, but that when you do that, it gets erased.

So the first thing to do is:

```
private final HashSet<Integer> pSet = new HashSet<>(); // Changed to private
```

The problem, then, is that your calling code has to say

```
Number n = new Number(15); // Or whatever number you're calling it with
```

so every time you call it, it gets a fresh copy of Number and your Set is gone.

So instead, make your calling code only create one Number(), but have a new method in Number that looks like:

```
public void setNumber(int n){
    number = n;
}
```

Then every time you want to call number, you can call

```
number.setNumber(5);
number.isBoolean();
```